# Python: generate secure temporary file name

Tags: python, unit-testing, standard-library, temporary-files

In the context of writing unit tests for a backend class, I need a secure way to generate a temporary file name. My current approach is:

```
fp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
fp.close()
with Backend(fp.name) as backend:
    ...run the test...
os.unlink(fp.name)
```

This is a bit awkward. Does there exist a standard library context manager which allows to achieve the same by:

```
with TempFileName() as name:
    with Backend(name) as backend:
        ...run the test...
```

---

### Current Solution

It appears that no pre-made context manager exists. I am now using:

```
class TemporaryBackend(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.fp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
        self.fp.close()
        self.backend = Backend(self.fp.name)

    def __enter__(self):
        return self.backend

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.backend.close()
        os.unlink(self.fp.name)
```

Which can then be used with:

```
with TemporaryBackend() as backend:
    ...run the test...
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than creating a temporary *file*, create a temporary *directory* which only you have access to. Once you have that, you can simply use an arbitrary string as the name of a file in that directory.

```
d = tempfile.mkdtemp()
tmp_name = "somefile.txt"
with Backend(os.path.join(d, tmp_name)) as backend:
    ... run test ...
os.remove(tmp_name)   # If necessary
os.rmdir(d)
```

Depending on your needs, you may just want a random string of characters:

```
with Backend(''.join(random.sample(string.lowercase, 8))) as backend:
    ... run test ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The creation of unique file names relays on the ability of file systems to grant exclusive access to files. So one have to create a file, not only a file name.

Another way to have a place, where you can create files safely, is, to create a temporary directory and put your files inside this directory. This would be my preferred way for test cases.

Comment: _So one have to create a file, not only a file name._ I agree. This is exactly what my code does. I am looking for a context manager that packages this more nicely.